# How do I add 2 to the unicode value of every char. It only changes the first char.. Ex. Input : ab. Output : cb

Tags: java, unicode

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TESTING45363

{

    public static void main(String[] arg)

    {

    String word;  
      int index = 0;
      char [] word2;
      System.out.print("Input Letter: ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      word = input.nextLine();
      word2 = word.toCharArray();
      input.close();

      for (int i = 0; i <= word2.length; i++);

      {

         switch (word2[index])      

          {

            case 'a': word2[index] = 97 + 2; break;
            case 'b': word2[index] = 98 + 2; break;
            case 'c': word2[index] = 99 + 2; break;
            case 'd': word2[index] = 100 + 2; break;
            case 'e': word2[index] = 101 + 2; break;
            case 'f': word2[index] = 102 + 2; break;
            case 'g': word2[index] = 103 + 2; break;
            case 'h': word2[index] = 104 + 2; break;
            case 'i': word2[index] = 105 + 2; break;
            case 'j': word2[index] = 106 + 2; break;
            case 'k': word2[index] = 107 + 2; break;
            case 'l': word2[index] = 108 + 2; break;
            case 'm': word2[index] = 109 + 2; break;
            case 'n': word2[index] = 110 + 2; break;
            case 'o': word2[index] = 111 + 2; break;
            case 'p': word2[index] = 112 + 2; break;
            case 'q': word2[index] = 113 + 2; break;
            case 'r': word2[index] = 114 + 2; break;
            case 's': word2[index] = 115 + 2; break;
            case 't': word2[index] = 116 + 2; break;
            case 'u': word2[index] = 117 + 2; break;
            case 'v': word2[index] = 118 + 2; break;
            case 'w': word2[index] = 119 + 2; break;
            case 'x': word2[index] = 120 + 2; break;
            case 'y': word2[index] = 121 - 24; break;
            case 'z': word2[index] = 122 - 24; break;

         }

         index = index + 1;

      } 

      String newString1 = new String(word2);
      System.out.println("New word: " + newString1);

   }

}
```

How do I add 2 to the unicode value of every char. It only changes the first char.. Ex. Input : ab. Output : cb! Plz Help. I have had no luck so far.

Comment: I'm sure you can think of a more efficient way to write that `switch` statement.

Comment: What suggestions do you have?

Comment: How about `if (word2[index] >= 'a' && word2[index]<='x') { word2[index] += 2; } else if (word2[index] =='y' || word2[index] == 'z') { word2[index] -= 24; }` perhaps?

Comment: You also don't need both `i` and `index` - right now, the two of them are equal throughout your loop.

Comment: Would I have the if statements in my for loop?

Comment: If you read up on what "for" does and what "if" does, I'm sure you'll be able to figure that out for yourself @OwainDavies

Answer (score 1):

First, remove that semicolon at the end of your `for` loop statement.  It acts as the body, and the block that follows is executed only once.

Next, stop the loop before you reach `word2.length`; Java indices run from `0` through `length - 1`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < word2.length; i++)
```

Comment: It says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Comment: When I make the changes in my answer, it works for me.  `wxyz` -> `yzab`.

Comment: I didn't make any additions.  I changed your `for` loop line to the code in my answer.

Comment: Besides removing the semi colon and changing <= to < what do I do?

Comment: Those are the only changes I made.  First make that change and ensure that it works.  After that, for cleaner code, you can replace your `switch` statement as @DavidWallace suggests.

Comment: Would David Wallace's if and else-if statements be inserted into a for loop, if so what would the for loop be?